# DetailsView - "edit" button calling javascript function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, detailsview

I have a number of DetailsView-Controls, whose visibility I toggle with a simple jQuery-function. Rough outline: the user presses a link "PERSONAL", and the  containing the DetailsView for "PERSONAL" appears, while all the other DetailsView-`<divs>` disappear. Default state for all these `<divs>` is hidden.

Now there's the following problem: once the user presses the generated EDIT-button of a DetailsView-Control, the page gets a postback, and all the divs are hidden again.

I see the following possibilities (maybe you see more?):

1. change the jQuery function, that the s need to be explicitly hidden
2. don't let the edit-button be created automatically, but add a custom button to each DV (with `'onclick=javascript: ...'`), which would mean that I also need to add the "UPDATE" and "CANCEL" buttons
3. find a way to add the `'onclick=javascript: ...'`-property to the existing EDIT button

Of course I would prefer #3 ;), or maybe someone has a better idea?
The problem at #1 is that my jQuery is kind of 'not so good', the problem with #2 is that I would have to create these buttons / functions for quite some DVs.

Thanks in advance! :)

---

Edit; by the way here is the jQuery snippet that controls my

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleVisibility(newSection) {

        $(".details_container").not("#" + newSection).hide();
        $("#" + newSection).show();
    }
</script>
```

All my divs to be controlled are with the class "details_container". Maybe there's 2 lines of code to add some sort of "this-is-my-active-div", which can be easily done?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide aspx code for this button ?

Assuming it's ImageButton
In `RowDataBound` event

```
 ((ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Attributes.add("onclick", "return YourFunction();");
```

Comment: Well, there's the problem - I just set the AutoGenerateEditButton-property of my DV to "true" (in order to have the whole edit-mode-functionality given). I checked the stuff i can access in the RowDataBound event, but there's only the DataRows themselves, but no sign of the CommandRow (where the created EDIT-button is located). I would have added my function to the button in similar fashion you suggest, but as said, I don't know how to access the button.

Comment: so the problem maybe is with AutoGenerateEditButton, maybe you can add it manually in DV desiner and then you will have it in code

Comment: That's right, as I pointed out ... actually I can add a templatefield to the DV and add the buttons manually, but then I would have to write the whole edit/update/canel-functionality myself, which looks quite tough on the first thought.

Comment: but i dont mean TemplateField, i mean -  in DV menu - Edit Fields ->CommandFields ->Edit,Delete... ->Add

Comment: I can see the AutoGeneratedEdit button in the Fields-Menu of the DV, yes, but I can not assign any sort of additional properties to the buttons/links themselves ... good try though, thanks!

Comment: becouse you have to uncheck "auto-generate fields" checkbox in this menu

Comment: It is unchecked. By the way, the link of the rendered button is javascript:__doPostBack('dv_details_personal','Edit$0') ... even if I try to add my function BEFORE or AFTER this, it doesn't work. So I guess I will have to switch to server sided div-visibility, and get rid of the jQuery .. :/

Comment: yeah that it some idea  this server side solution, you can also wrap this div content into UpdatePanel and then PostBacks won't bother you. I'm still wondering why you cannot manage this edit button, i added myself one to DV and i have it in aspx file <commandfield>

Answer (score 0):

If you need to only care about showing and Hiding Divs,i would suggest to set a global variable to know which div is visible....
e.g.
public ind VisibleDivId=1 //That means first div is visible.(Set it as Public)

On Edit Button Click event set the Variable Value.i.e. If Edit of second DetailsView is clicked then set VisibleDivId=2

In Body Load Call The Javascript Function to Show Hide the Divs

```
function ShowHide()
{

var DivId=<%=VisibleDivId %>
//Code to Show Hide Div.

}
```

**Else**
You can also call Javascript Function from the Edit Event also

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Key", "ShowHide();", true);
```